# Язык программирования для написания высокопроизводительных Web-приложений

Tags: веб-программирование

Помогите с выбором языка, который бы обеспечивал наибольшую производительность Web-приложений. Стоит сказать, что С/C++ наверное не очень для этого подходят.  Суть в том что я хочу найти ЯП очень хорошо подходящий для веб но значительно превосходящий по производительности PHP,Python, Ruby и т д.

Comment: Как раз таки С для высокопроизводительности наиболее подходит.

Comment: Критерием для такого языка есть наличие хотя бы сборщика мусора.

Comment: стесняюсь спросить, а для каких таких целей вам не хватает производительности тех языков, что обычно используются для написания веб-приложений?

Comment: генерация изображений расчетных схем для задач по сопротивлению материалов, проблема в том что за один раз таких схем нужно создать более сотни с чем Python не справляется наилучшим образом

Comment: А чем так важно наличие сборщика мусора?

А к ответу -- http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2011/03/preliminary-warp-cross-language-benchmarks и http://snapframework.com/blog/2010/11/17/snap-0.3-benchmarks

Comment: В процессе работы не хотелось бы уделять много внимания на работу с памятью. Тем более когда речь идет о большом количестве динамически создаваемых объектах.

Comment: @andreycrane, а для  приложения с большим количеством динамически создаваемых объектов именно проблема памяти может стать решающей.

Далеко не факт, что сборщик мусора способен ее эффективно решить.

И Python у Вас не справляется возможно из-за его прожорливости в памяти.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Честно говоря, вы дали мало информации по вашей проблеме, поэтому сложно сразу дать какое-то абсолютно правильное решение. Но вообще генерация большого количества изображений по какому-то алгоритму - задача сама по себе достаточно ресурсоемкая (к этому можно еще добавить то, что если алгоритм этой генерации реализован через ж..эммм..не лучшим образом, то она может стать на n порядков более требовательной в плане ресурсов)
Вполне возможно, что для этих задач имеет смысл задействовать GPU, используя OpenGL или DirectX - один только процессор с такими проблемами справляется неважно. 
Что касается языков, то из используемых в вебе ЯП вполне приличная производительность у C#  - как показывает практика, в некоторых аспектах он даже обгоняет C++. (впрочем, не уверен, что в работе с изображениями это будет иметь весомое значение)

Еще добавлю, что, наверное, стоит рассмотреть вариант с написанием библиотеки на C/C++, которая будет выполнять работу с изображениями, и подключать ее из вашег оприложения. Понятия не имею, как там с этим в Питоне (не знаком с ним вовсе), но в том же Шарпе это вполне себе возможно

Comment: Дело даже не в генерации изображений. Скорее хотелось бы владеть языком программирования при использовании которого не пришлось бы задумываться об производительности как о первостепенной проблеме. В плане C# не очень то лучшее для меня решение, хотелось бы использовать его на других не Windows ОС, а Mono очередной костыль. Наверное стоит обратить внимание на Java или Go.

Comment: > Mono очередной костыль

В чем состоит его костыльность?

Comment: Просто не радует тот факт, что все лучшее в C# появляется в Mono гораздо позже чем в изначальном .NET

Comment: Извините, а чего же такого, по-вашему, нет в Mono-реализации C# из того, что есть в C# от Microsoft?

Comment: Я не настолько хорошо подкован в С# признаю. Но и не заинтерисован в нем.

Comment: Вы не заинтересованы в том, чтобы знать язык, который, возможно, решает вашу проблему?

Тогда непонятно, какого ответа вы от нас ждёте. Вы хотите, чтобы мы посоветовали один из тех языков, которые вам нравятся? Огласите весь список, пожалуйста!

Comment: А я скажу, чего [нет в Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Compatibility). WPF и ASP.NET 4.5. Ни то, ни другое вам не понадобится.

Comment: @VladD а WPF в mono точно нет?

Comment: @alexlz: по крайней мере, на их сайте написано, что нет. (Ссылка в предыдущем комментарии.) А жаль!

Comment: >А я скажу, чего нет в Mono. WPF и ASP.NET 4.5

да, я в курсе, что в Mono этого нет, но я имел в виду сам язык, а не сопутствующую "инфраструктуру". А вот именно язык в Mono реализован, если не ошибаюсь, целиком (ну или почти целиком)